# Date removed from x axis on overlaid plots matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to show time series lines representing an effort amount  using matplotlib and pandas.

I've got my DF's to all to overlay in one plot, however when I do python seems to strip the x axis of the date and input some numbers. (I'm not sure where these come from but at a guess, not all days contain the same data so python has reverted to using an index id number). If I plot any one of these they come up with date on the x-axis.

Any hints or solutions to make the x axis show date for the multiple plot would be much appreciated.

This is the single figure plot with time axis:
[image: single figure plot with time axis]

Code I'm using to plot is

```
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(b342,color='black')
ax.plot(b343,color='blue')
ax.plot(b344,color='red')
ax.plot(b345,color='green')
ax.plot(b346,color='pink')
ax.plot(fi,color='yellow')
plt.show()
```

This is the multiple plot fig with weird x axis:
[image: multiple plots without time axis]

Comment: I should say all the DF's have the same date instance as their index

Comment: what version of mpl are you using?  This may 'just work' in 1.5.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to manually specify the x-axis based on the DataFrame index, and then plot directly using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make up some data
n = 100
dates = pd.date_range(start = "2015-01-01", periods = n, name = "yearDate")

dfs = []

for i in range(3):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.random(n)*(i + 1), index = dates,
                      columns = ["FishEffort"] )
    df.df_name = str(i)
    dfs.append(df)

# plot it directly using matplotlib instead of through the DataFrame
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

for df in dfs:
    plt.plot(df.index,df["FishEffort"], label = df.df_name)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another option would be to concatenate your DataFrames and plot using Pandas. If you give your "FishEffort" field the correct label name when loading the data or via `DataFrame.rename` then the labels will be specified automatically.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
dates = pd.date_range(start = "2015-01-01", periods = n, name = "yearDate")

dfs = []

for i in range(3):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.random(n)*(i + 1), index = dates,
                      columns = ["DataFrame #" + str(i) ] )
    df.df_name = str(i)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1)
df.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer that does what I want, it seems that calling plt.plot wasn't using the date as the x axis, however calling it using the pandas documentation did the trick.

```
ax = b342.plot(label='342')
b343.plot(ax=ax, label='test')
b344.plot(ax=ax)
b345.plot(ax=ax)
b346.plot(ax=ax)
fi.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]plt.show()

I was wondering if anyone knew hwo to change the labels here?